# Convert binary to hex IPv6

Tags: ipv6

I have a binary sequence that is supposed to be an IPv6 and I am not sure if I've converted it correctly, can you please check and tell me if it's wrong?

Here is the binary sequence:

```
0000000000000000 0001100000000000 0000011000000000 0000000000000000 0000000001100000 0000000000011000 0000000000000110 0000000000000001
```

and here is what I got:

```
0:1800:600::60:18:6:1
```

Thanks!

Update: here is the algorithm that I used to generate the hex values:

*IPv6 is consisted of 128 bits, I devide it into 8 different groups of 16 bits,
get a group of 16 bits and devide it into 4 groups of 4 bits
then I convert every group of 4 bits into hex, join the 4 different values I get,
then repeat for the rest (7 groups) of 16 bits(2B).
After that I add ':' between every group of (now) hex values.
Find and remove the zeros from the front of the groups, then, 
find the biggest subsequence that are consisted only of zeros,
remove them and leave only "::" instead.*

Comment: Did you do this by hand? If so, it seems rather specific and off-topic for a programming site to just present this one example. If not, perhaps you could show the code you used to create it, and someone would be able to tell you if it is implemented correctly.

Comment: well, yes I did it by hand, but I first need to learn how to convert it by hand so I can build a program that will do that for me, that is why I posted it here as a question. I am very sorry for the off-topic

Comment: That's fine, but perhaps you could describe the algorithm that you followed to calculate it. Otherwise, the best anyone can do is say "yes, that particular example is right", or "no, that particular example should be XXX", neither of which will actually tell you if you're on the right lines or not.

Comment: The decoding looks correct, but the result is not an IPv6 address that should be in use as it is from a reserved range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was an IPv6 address, your decoding would be correct (modulo some endianess issues that would result in reordering of bytes). Unfortunately, every set of 128 bits can be an IPv6 address. As @Sander Steffann noted, the IPv6 address you calculated is not currently valid. [RFC 4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291) describes the IPv6 Addressing Architecture, and the [IANA IPv6 Address Space Assignments](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-address-space/ipv6-address-space.xhtml) show which allowed addresses are reserved for what. For addresses starting with eight zeroes (0000::/8), there are only the following valid ranges: The unspecified address, only consisting of zeroes (::/128); the loopback address (::1/128); IPv4 mapped addresses (::ffff:0:0/96), which are starting with 80 zero bits; and the deprecated "IPv4-compatible IPv6 addresses" (0000::/96), which even start with 96 zero bits.

---

But the other problem I have with that bit sequence: it looks too regular. Let's see what happens, if we count the ones and zeroes with a bit of Perl:

```
$ echo "0000000000000000 0001100000000000 0000011000000000 0000000000000000 0000000001100000 0000000000011000 0000000000000110 0000000000000001" | perl -wple 's/ //g; s/(0+|1+)/length($1)."x".substr($1,0,1)." "/ge'
19x0 2x1 16x0 2x1 34x0 2x1 16x0 2x1 16x0 2x1 16x0 1x1
```

(The code just substitutes every sequence of 1s or 0s with the length, a "x" and the first character of the sequence.)

If we exclude the start and end, we always have a sequence of 16 zeroes, then two ones. (In the middle, we have two zeroes instead of the ones, so a sequence of 34 zeroes in total.)

Maybe you're looking at the wrong part of your bit sequence?

Comment: No, this is just a sample that my proffesor gave us to translate with the IPv6 rules...
The catch was to just create an IPv6 in hex form, not to check whether the address is valid, I guess that is up next. Anyway, thank you a lot for the thorogh answer, it made things really clearer to me

Comment: @Mark Glad I could help. But in the future please state when a question is an exercise or homework (where the data need not make sense). Sander's answer would have been sufficient here.